# Is FB.IsLoggedIn delay after FB.Init?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have some problem about FB sessions on `Facebook Unity SDK`.

`FB.IsLoggendIn` return `false` every time that make me login every time when app launching. Like below this-

```
void MethodA()
{
   Debug.Log(FB.IsLoggendIn);
}

FB.Init(MethodA);
```

But if I waiting more second and I Debug it again. It's return me TRUE.
I don't know what happen about this. Delay for get Token? Session or something and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved now with this fix.

For iOS,
In IOSFacebook.cs

```
private void OnInitComplete(string msg)
{
    externalInitDelegate(); // move this line
    if(msg != null && msg.Length > 0)
    {
        OnLogin (msg);
    }
    externalInitDelegate(); // to this line
}
```

For Android,
In AndroidFacebook.cs

```
public void OnInitComplete(string message)
{
    OnLoginComplete(message); // to this line
    if (this.onInitComplete != null)
    {
        this.onInitComplete();
    }
    OnLoginComplete(message); // move this line
}
```

Comment: Hi Peerawit, this is just a bug on our part. OnLoginComplete should be called after FB.Login, not after FB.Init. Thank you for debugging this for us, and for using the SDK.